# Changing locale not being applied in Blazor server-side app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have implemented localization of a Blazor Server-side app (NET6) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#dynamically-set-the-culture-by-user-preference-1). I created 3 `resx` files:

```
Resources.en-US.resx
Resources.de-DE.resx
Resources.sv-SE.resx
```

I added the following in `Startup.cs` just below `services.AddMvc` in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

And the following in the `Configure` method below `app.UseRouting();`

```
var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "de-DE", "sv-SE" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

I then created an empty razor component, added the the culture controller as described in the article and modified my razor components to have the following:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<Empty> localizer

@(localizer["LanguageSelectLocale"])
```

The controller action to change the locale is being called, but the locale is not being changed. Also, with the above setup, I'm setting my keys in the pages and not the localized strings.

I would like to use one resource file per locale.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Resource file naming, you could find

> The Resources are named for the full type name of their class minus
> the assembly name. For example, a French resource in a project whose
> main assembly is LocalizationWebsite.Web.dll for the class
> LocalizationWebsite.Web.Startup would be named Startup.fr.resx. A
> resource for the class
> LocalizationWebsite.Web.Controllers.HomeController would be named
> Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx. If your targeted class's namespace
> isn't the same as the assembly name you will need the full type name.
> For example, in the sample project a resource for the type
> ExtraNamespace.Tools would be named ExtraNamespace.Tools.fr.resx.
>
> In the sample project, the ConfigureServices method sets the
> ResourcesPath to "Resources", so the project relative path for the
> home controller's French resource file is
> Resources/Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx. Alternatively, you can
> use folders to organize resource files. For the home controller, the
> path would be Resources/Controllers/HomeController.fr.resx. If you
> don't use the ResourcesPath option, the .resx file would go in the
> project base directory. The resource file for HomeController would be
> named Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx. The choice of using the dot
> or path naming convention depends on how you want to organize your
> resource files.

The reason why your application is not working well, is you use the wrong name for the resource file.

For example, if you want to set Localization for CultureExample2.razor, the resource name should be  `Pages.CultureExample2.en-US.resx` , `Pages.CultureExample2.es-CL.resx` inside the resource file and then it will work well.

Component:

```
@page "/culture-example-2"
@using System.Globalization
@inject IStringLocalizer<CultureExample2> Loc

<h1>Culture Example 2</h1>

<p>
    <b>CurrentCulture</b>: @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
</p>

<h2>Greeting</h2>

<p>
    @Loc["Greeting"]
</p>

<p>
    @greeting
</p>

@code {
    private string? greeting;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        greeting = Loc["Greeting"];
    }
}
```

Like below:

[image]

---

Update create two new resource:

[image]

Create a new class:

```
public class SharedResource
{
}
```

Usage:

```
@page "/culture-example-2"
@using System.Globalization
@inject IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> Loc

<h1>Culture Example 2</h1>

<p>
    <b>CurrentCulture</b>: @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
</p>

<h2>Greeting</h2>

<p>
    @Loc["Greeting"]
</p>

<p>
    @greeting
</p>

@code {
    private string? greeting;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        greeting = Loc["Greeting"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I need just one resource file per locale.

Comment: If you want to just resource file per locate, I suggest you could create a dummy class which named shared resource and then use it inside the component. More details, you could refer to my update answer.

Comment: I created an `App.resx` as there is already an `App.razor`. This should work I guess.

Comment: Yes, it will work. Besides, if you think my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer, so that other folks could find the answer more easily. Thank you.